# Issues With ARIA2C and basic auth- WGET working

Tags: ubuntu, aria2

I'm having some issues getting aria2c working with basic http auth. Wget works perfectly, but I'd like to use arias multi-threading features

```
!!link!! = https://www.site.com/directory/name
```

Command that works in WGET:

```
wget --user=username --password=123password# !!link!!/file.txt
```

Command that does not work in aria2c:

```
aria2c --log=arialog --http-user=username --http-passwd=123password# --check-certificate=false !!link!!/file.txt
```

The error received is

```
-> [HttpSkipResponseCommand.cc:207] errorCode=24 Authorization failed.
```

In the log, the response back from the server is:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 22 Aug 2014 01:40:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="directory", nonce="ZI2m7S0BBQA=07cfdbd25e8bab3d41ad643d0a6d0fb98ecef695", algorithm=MD5, domain="/var/www/directory/ http://www.site.com/directory", qop="auth"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The SSL labs report on my domain, reports back fine and I am not getting and trust issues in any other product.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could this be because my server is using digest authentication?

Excerpt from log:

Host: site.com
Authorization: Basic ********

Answer (score 1):

According to this comparison, aria2 does not support http digest auth: [Link to curl comparison table](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html)

Comment: It is supported now.